# QGIS Query builder query

Tags: qgis, sql, query

In the attribute table I can use this expression

```
left(   "CODE" ,1)='E' or left( "CODE" ,1)='W'
```

to select features successfully, but when I try to use the same expression in the Properties, General, Query Builder window, to display a subset of features on the map it gives an error:

> SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected LEFT

Is there an alternative syntax I can use in the Properties dialog to achieve the same?

Comment: Found the answer - you use substr(   "CODE" ,1,1)='E' and it works!